# Dropbox-like system tray application

Tags: windows, user-interface, dropbox, system-tray

I am planning to create an application that resides on the windows system tray that behaves and looks like the Dropbox UI in Windows (Not sure if it looks different on other OS).

What is the best language/framework to get started with this?

Here is screenshot of what the UI looks like.

[image]

Comment: did you make one in the end :)?